# Анимированное меню HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Требуется, чтобы при наведении мыши на каждый пункт меню буквы в нём слева направо постепенно заменялись на заглавные. А когда мышь уходит с пункта, так же постепенно заменялись строчными. Я придумал только как сделать это через массив:

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menuone" href="https://google.com/">home</a></li>
      <li><a id="menuone1" href="https://microsoft.com/ru-ru">about</a></li>
      <li><a id="menuone2" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let menus = document.getElementById('menuone');

      let mass = ['home', 'Home', 'HOme', 'HOMe', 'HOME'];

      let b = 0,
        startn, startm, isMouseHover = false;

      menus.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        isMouseHover = true;
        clearInterval(startm);
        b = b + 1;
        if (b == mass.length) {
          b = 4;
        }
        event.target.textContent = mass[b];
        startn = setInterval(ssp, 1000 / 5);
      }, false);

      function ssp() {
        b = b + 1;
        if (b >= mass.length) {
          b = 4;
        }
        menus.innerHTML = mass[b];
      }
      menus.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
        isMouseHover = false;
        clearInterval(startn);
        b = b - 1;
        if (b <= 0) {
          b = 0;
          clearInterval(startm);
        }
        event.target.textContent = mass[b];
        startm = setInterval(ssm, 1000 / 5);
      }, false);

      function ssm() {
        b = b - 1;
        if (b <= 0) {
          b = 0;
        }
        menus.innerHTML = mass[b];
      }
    </script>

  </div>
</body>
```

Но такой способ не подходит. Как можно реализовать такое меню иначе? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: "Но такой способ не подходит." - кому не подходит и почему?

Comment: Не важно кому не подходит, суть то не в этом) Мне, например, так как чтобы изменить 1 пункт меню требуется менять весь массив, слышал что есть более легкие способы реализации данного меню, поэтому и спросил у людей совета.

Comment: Раз спрашиваю - значит важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.menu ul li a {
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="menuone" href="https://google.com/">home, sweet home</a></li>
      <li><a id="menuone1" href="https://microsoft.com/ru-ru">about apples</a></li>
      <li><a id="menuone2" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">the walrus and the carpenter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul li a');

      menus.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        clearInterval(event.target.startMore);
        clearInterval(event.target.startLess);
        event.target.startMore = setInterval(moreUpper, 1000 / 5, event.target);
      }, false));

      function moreUpper(el) {
        let text = el.textContent;
        let upper = text.toUpperCase();
        if (text == upper) {
          clearInterval(el.startMore);
          return;
        }
        text = text.split('');
        upper = upper.split('');
        for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if (text[i] != upper[i]) {
            text[i] = upper[i];
            el.textContent = text.join('');
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      menus.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
        clearInterval(event.target.startMore);
        clearInterval(event.target.startLess);
        event.target.startLess = setInterval(lessUpper, 1000 / 5, event.target);
      }, false));

      function lessUpper(el) {
        let text = el.textContent;
        let lower = text.toLowerCase();
        if (text == lower) {
          clearInterval(el.startLess);
          return;
        }
        text = text.split('');
        lower = lower.split('');
        for (let i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (text[i] != lower[i]) {
            text[i] = lower[i];
            el.textContent = text.join('');
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на CSS, правда в одну сторону.

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('#nav a'),
    delay = 100;

[...links].map(e => {
  let split = e.innerText.split(''),
      html = '';
  split.map((e, i) => {
    html += `<span style="animation-delay: ${delay * i}ms;">${e}</span>`;
  });
  e.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#nav a:hover > span {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  animation: toUpper .1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes toUpper {
  from {text-transform: lowercase;}
  to {text-transform: uppercase;}
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```